# Change my location button direction and icon in the Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have default `MyLocation` button on the Jetpack Compose's map but I want to move the `Botton` in the bottom and right and change the button icon but I don't know how can I do this in the Jetpack Compose.

**My map view screen:**

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { mapView }
) {
    mapView.getMapAsync { map ->
        map.apply {
            if (permissionsState){
                isMyLocationEnabled = true
            }
            uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
            navigatorViewModel.apply {
                scope.launch {
                    lastSelectedLocation.collect {
                        val position = LatLng(
                            it.lat,
                            it.lng
                        )
                        moveCamera(
                            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                position,
                                Constants.ZOOM_CAMERA
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
                scope.launch {
                    setOnCameraIdleListener {
                        val cameraPosition = map.cameraPosition
                        setLocation(
                            LocationModel(
                                lat = cameraPosition.target.latitude,
                                lng = cameraPosition.target.longitude
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's a standard part of the map where users expect to find it. What is your real objective?

Comment: @Johann It's in our design

Comment: Sorry to bother but did you manage to find a solution to it? A way to move the button to the button to the bottom right corner/ modify the button layout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an overlay and place your custom button there.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).